# derive general solution to first-order inhomogeneous pde

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Given $u_t+cu_x=b(x,t)$ with initial value $u(x,0)=\phi(x)$, I am asked to derive the following general solution
$$u=\phi(x-ct)+\int_{0}^t b(x-c(t-\tau),\tau)d\tau$$

I am not sure how to proceed with this $b(x,t)$. I have solved such PDE where the explicit form of $b(x,t)$ given, but not in the general case. I tried the method of characteristics,
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{c}=\frac{du}{b(x,t)}$$
but got stuck. Hope someone could help! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$u_t+cu_x=b(x,t)$$
You have correctly written the Charpit-Lagrange system of ODEs :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{c}=\frac{du}{b(x,t)}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{c}$ :
$$x-ct=C_1\quad\implies\quad x=C_1+ct$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $dt=\frac{du}{b(x,t)}=\frac{du}{b\left(C_1+ct\:,\:t\right)}$
$$du-b\left(C_1+ct\:,\:t\right)dt=0$$
$$u-\int_0^t b\left(C_1+c\tau\:,\:\tau\right)d\tau=C_2$$

The general solution of the PDE $\quad C_2=\phi(C_1)\quad$ is :
$$u-\int_0^t b\left((x-ct)+c\tau\:,\:\tau\right)d\tau=\phi(x-ct)$$

$\phi$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to some initial condition).
$$u=\phi(x-ct)+\int_{0}^t b(x-c(t-\tau),\tau)d\tau$$

Answer (score 0):

The general solution of equation $u_t+cu_x=b(x,t)$ is sum of general solution of homogenous equation $u_t+cu_x=0$ and the particular solution of inhomogenous equation $u_t+cu_x=b(x,t)$.

1. General solution of homogenous equation $u_t+cu_x=0$ can be obtained using method of characteristics. We compose the equation of characteristics $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{c}$, and obtain its the first integral $x - c t$. So, general solution of homogenous equation is $u(x, t) = \psi(x - c t)$, where $\psi$ is a continuous-differentiable function.
2. The particular solution of equation $u_t+cu_x=b(x,t)$. We build it using extra condition $u(0, t) = 0$. It can be obtained using Fourier transform: $u(x, t) \overset{\mathcal{F}}{\rightarrow} \hat{u}(\omega,t)$
   $$
   \hat{u}(\omega,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp(-i\omega x) u(x, t) dx,
   $$
   $$
   u(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp(i\omega x)\hat{u}(\omega, t) d\omega.
   $$
   For function $\hat{u}$ we get the Cauchy problem $\hat{u}_t+i \omega c \hat{u}=\hat{b}(\omega,t)$, $\hat{u}|_{t=0} = 0$. After solving it, we obtain formula
   $$
   \hat{u}(\omega,t) = \int\limits_0^t \exp(i \omega c (\tau - t)) \hat{b}(\omega,\tau) d\tau.
   $$
   So,
   $$
   u(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left(\int\limits_0^t \exp(i \omega c (\tau - t)) \hat{b}(\omega,\tau) d\tau \right) \exp(i\omega x) d\omega,
   $$
   or
   $$
   u(x,t) = \int\limits_0^t \frac{d\tau}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  \exp(i \omega c (\tau - t)) \hat{b}(\omega,\tau) \exp(i\omega x) d\omega.
   $$
   After calculating it using $\exp(i \omega c (\tau - t)) \overset{\mathcal{F}^{-1}}{\rightarrow} \sqrt{2 \pi} \delta (x - c (t -\tau))$ and convolution theorem, we obtain

$$u(x, t)=\int_{0}^t b(x-c(t-\tau),\tau)d\tau.$$

3. So, the general solution of equation $u_t+cu_x=b(x,t)$ is
   $$
   u(x, t)=\psi(x - c t) + \int_{0}^t b(x-c(t-\tau),\tau)d\tau,
   $$
   where $\psi$ is a continuous-differentiable function. Substituting it into Cauchy condition $u(x, 0)=\phi(x)$ leads to $u(x, 0)=\psi(x)=\phi(x)$.
4. Thus,
   $$
   u(x, t)=\phi(x - c t) + \int_{0}^t b(x-c(t-\tau),\tau)d\tau,
   $$
   is the solution of your Cauchy problem.